# How to convert SVG files to HTML5's canvas?

Tags: html, svg, canvas

Is there a way to convert SVG files to HTML5's canvas compatible commands?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's no 100% solution, but there are script libraries that can convert a subset of svg to canvas, e.g http://code.google.com/p/canvas-svg/. There's also the experimental [Path2D](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Path2D/Path2D) API that can draw an svg path data string onto the canvas, not sure how well it's supported across browsers though.

Comment: lake of documentation, not explained answer.. -1

Answer (score 23):

[**canvg**](http://code.google.com/p/canvg/) seems to be a better solution. It is an active project as of January 2012.

[canvas-svg](http://code.google.com/p/canvas-svg/) hasn't been updated since it was published in June 2009.

Comment: Can't download canvas-svg.

Answer (score 21):

There is `Save as: HTML5 canvas` command in **Inkscape** (free software for vector graphic).

https://inkscape.org/en/

It is also very useful/powerful vector drawing application.

If you create SVG image like this:

[image]

You can expect export results like this:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Inkscape Output</title>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id='canvas' width='640' height='400'></canvas>
    <script>
    var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
        
// #layer1
    ctx.save();
    ctx.transform(1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.665980);
    
// #path3342
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.lineJoin = 'round';
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgb(194, 199, 202)';
    ctx.lineWidth = 6.964493;
    ctx.miterLimit = 10;
    ctx.moveTo(177.895580, 392.397380);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(162.429960, 392.397380, 149.892650, 379.989530, 149.892650, 364.683620);
    ctx.lineTo(149.892650, 187.607910);
    ctx.lineTo(149.892650, 171.841360);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(149.892650, 164.491270, 152.842960, 157.442080, 158.094510, 152.244760);
    ctx.lineTo(299.609330, 12.191281);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(304.860880, 6.993960, 311.983620, 4.074117, 319.410400, 4.074117);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(331.009610, 4.074117, 337.622310, 10.618525, 340.800640, 13.764037);
    ctx.lineTo(480.726290, 152.244760);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(485.977840, 157.442080, 488.928150, 164.491270, 488.928150, 171.841360);
    ctx.lineTo(488.928150, 364.683620);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(488.928150, 379.989530, 476.390840, 392.397380, 460.925220, 392.397380);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.restore();
    
// #layer2
    ctx.save();
    ctx.transform(1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.665980);
    
// #path4326
    ctx.save();
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.transform(1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, -0.297688, -300.245660);
    ctx.lineJoin = 'round';
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgb(68, 143, 228)';
    ctx.lineCap = 'round';
    ctx.miterLimit = 4;
    ctx.lineWidth = 4.000000;
    ctx.moveTo(304.365780, 475.555440);
    ctx.lineTo(304.365780, 619.603740);
    ctx.lineTo(278.258230, 619.603740);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.restore();
    
// #path4326-0
    ctx.save();
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.transform(1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, -0.297688, -300.245660);
    ctx.lineJoin = 'round';
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgb(68, 143, 228)';
    ctx.lineCap = 'round';
    ctx.miterLimit = 4;
    ctx.lineWidth = 4.000000;
    ctx.moveTo(336.711080, 475.530360);
    ctx.lineTo(336.711080, 619.594590);
    ctx.lineTo(361.006650, 619.594590);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.restore();
    
// #path4343
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.lineJoin = 'round';
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgb(68, 143, 228)';
    ctx.lineCap = 'round';
    ctx.miterLimit = 4;
    ctx.lineWidth = 4.055327;
    ctx.moveTo(112.056510, 175.334020);
    ctx.lineTo(276.513300, 175.334020);
    ctx.stroke();
    
// #path4345
    ctx.save();
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.transform(1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, -0.297688, -300.245660);
    ctx.lineJoin = 'round';
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgb(68, 143, 228)';
    ctx.lineCap = 'round';
    ctx.miterLimit = 4;
    ctx.lineWidth = 4.000000;
    ctx.moveTo(528.297690, 475.579680);
    ctx.lineTo(368.297690, 475.579680);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.restore();
    ctx.restore();
    
// #Layer_1
    ctx.save();
    ctx.transform(1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, -0.297688, -299.579680);
    ctx.restore();
    
// #Layer_2
    ctx.save();
    ctx.transform(1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, -0.297688, -299.579680);
    
// #line3344
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgb(194, 199, 202)';
    ctx.lineWidth = 7.000000;
    ctx.miterLimit = 10;
    ctx.lineCap = 'round';
    ctx.moveTo(180.797680, 494.412660);
    ctx.lineTo(464.797700, 494.412660);
    ctx.stroke();
    
// #line3346
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgb(194, 199, 202)';
    ctx.lineWidth = 7.000000;
    ctx.miterLimit = 10;
    ctx.lineCap = 'round';
    ctx.moveTo(322.797700, 494.412660);
    ctx.lineTo(322.797700, 575.078670);
    ctx.stroke();
    
// #g4291
    ctx.save();
    ctx.transform(1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, -12.000000, 0.000000);
    
// #path3350
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(144, 218, 108)';
    ctx.moveTo(206.586690, 440.129660);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(206.586690, 439.949660, 206.688690, 439.783660, 206.853690, 439.693660);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(207.018690, 439.603660, 207.221690, 439.603660, 207.386690, 439.693660);
    ctx.lineTo(217.377690, 445.142660);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(217.542690, 445.232660, 217.644690, 445.398660, 217.644690, 445.578660);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(217.644690, 445.758660, 217.542690, 445.924660, 217.377690, 446.014660);
    ctx.lineTo(207.386690, 451.463660);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(207.221690, 451.553660, 207.018690, 451.553660, 206.853690, 451.463660);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(206.688690, 451.373660, 206.586690, 451.207660, 206.586690, 451.027660);
    ctx.lineTo(206.586690, 440.129660);
    ctx.fill();
    
// #path3352
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(144, 218, 108)';
    ctx.moveTo(226.586690, 440.129660);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(226.586690, 439.949660, 226.688690, 439.783660, 226.853690, 439.693660);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(227.018690, 439.603660, 227.221690, 439.603660, 227.386690, 439.693660);
    ctx.lineTo(237.377690, 445.142660);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(237.542690, 445.232660, 237.644690, 445.398660, 237.644690, 445.578660);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(237.644690, 445.758660, 237.542690, 445.924660, 237.377690, 446.014660);
    ctx.lineTo(227.386690, 451.463660);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(227.221690, 451.553660, 227.018690, 451.553660, 226.853690, 451.463660);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(226.688690, 451.373660, 226.586690, 451.207660, 226.586690, 451.027660);
    ctx.lineTo(226.586690, 440.129660);
    ctx.fill();
    
// #path3354
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(144, 218, 108)';
    ctx.moveTo(246.586690, 440.129660);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(246.586690, 439.949660, 246.688690, 439.783660, 246.853690, 439.693660);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(247.018690, 439.603660, 247.221690, 439.603660, 247.386690, 439.693660);
    ctx.lineTo(257.377690, 445.142660);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(257.542690, 445.232660, 257.644690, 445.398660, 257.644690, 445.578660);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(257.644690, 445.758660, 257.542690, 445.924660, 257.377690, 446.014660);
    ctx.lineTo(247.386690, 451.463660);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(247.221690, 451.553660, 247.018690, 451.553660, 246.853690, 451.463660);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(246.688690, 451.373660, 246.586690, 451.207660, 246.586690, 451.027660);
    ctx.lineTo(246.586690, 440.129660);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.restore();
    
// #g3356
    ctx.save();
    ctx.transform(1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, -261.202310, 183.745660);
    
// #path3358
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(68, 143, 228)';
    ctx.moveTo(658.123000, 256.384000);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(658.123000, 256.204000, 658.225000, 256.038000, 658.389000, 255.948000);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(658.554000, 255.858000, 658.758000, 255.858000, 658.922000, 255.948000);
    ctx.lineTo(668.913000, 261.397000);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(669.078000, 261.487000, 669.180000, 261.653000, 669.180000, 261.833000);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(669.180000, 262.013000, 669.078000, 262.179000, 668.913000, 262.269000);
    ctx.lineTo(658.922000, 267.718000);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(658.758000, 267.808000, 658.554000, 267.808000, 658.389000, 267.718000);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(658.225000, 267.628000, 658.123000, 267.462000, 658.123000, 267.282000);
    ctx.lineTo(658.123000, 256.384000);
    ctx.fill();
    
// #path3360
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(68, 143, 228)';
    ctx.moveTo(678.123000, 256.384000);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(678.123000, 256.204000, 678.225000, 256.038000, 678.389000, 255.948000);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(678.554000, 255.858000, 678.758000, 255.858000, 678.922000, 255.948000);
    ctx.lineTo(688.913000, 261.397000);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(689.078000, 261.487000, 689.180000, 261.653000, 689.180000, 261.833000);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(689.180000, 262.013000, 689.078000, 262.179000, 688.913000, 262.269000);
    ctx.lineTo(678.922000, 267.718000);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(678.758000, 267.808000, 678.554000, 267.808000, 678.389000, 267.718000);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(678.225000, 267.628000, 678.123000, 267.462000, 678.123000, 267.282000);
    ctx.lineTo(678.123000, 256.384000);
    ctx.fill();
    
// #path3362
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(68, 143, 228)';
    ctx.moveTo(698.123000, 256.384000);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(698.123000, 256.204000, 698.225000, 256.038000, 698.389000, 255.948000);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(698.554000, 255.858000, 698.758000, 255.858000, 698.922000, 255.948000);
    ctx.lineTo(708.913000, 261.397000);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(709.078000, 261.487000, 709.180000, 261.653000, 709.180000, 261.833000);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(709.180000, 262.013000, 709.078000, 262.179000, 708.913000, 262.269000);
    ctx.lineTo(698.922000, 267.718000);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(698.758000, 267.808000, 698.554000, 267.808000, 698.389000, 267.718000);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(698.225000, 267.628000, 698.123000, 267.462000, 698.123000, 267.282000);
    ctx.lineTo(698.123000, 256.384000);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.restore();
    
// #g4296
    ctx.save();
    ctx.transform(1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, -8.000000, 0.000000);
    
// #path3366
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(144, 218, 108)';
    ctx.moveTo(304.822690, 526.883660);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(305.002690, 526.883660, 305.168690, 526.985660, 305.258690, 527.149660);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(305.348690, 527.314660, 305.348690, 527.518660, 305.258690, 527.682660);
    ctx.lineTo(299.810690, 537.673660);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(299.720690, 537.838660, 299.554690, 537.940660, 299.373690, 537.940660);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(299.193690, 537.940660, 299.027690, 537.838660, 298.937690, 537.673660);
    ctx.lineTo(293.489690, 527.682660);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(293.398690, 527.518660, 293.398690, 527.314660, 293.489690, 527.149660);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(293.579690, 526.985660, 293.745690, 526.883660, 293.925690, 526.883660);
    ctx.lineTo(304.822690, 526.883660);
    ctx.fill();
    
// #path3368
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(144, 218, 108)';
    ctx.moveTo(304.822690, 546.883660);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(305.002690, 546.883660, 305.168690, 546.985660, 305.258690, 547.149660);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(305.348690, 547.314660, 305.348690, 547.518660, 305.258690, 547.682660);
    ctx.lineTo(299.810690, 557.673660);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(299.720690, 557.838660, 299.554690, 557.940660, 299.373690, 557.940660);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(299.193690, 557.940660, 299.027690, 557.838660, 298.937690, 557.673660);
    ctx.lineTo(293.489690, 547.682660);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(293.398690, 547.518660, 293.398690, 547.314660, 293.489690, 547.149660);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(293.579690, 546.985660, 293.745690, 546.883660, 293.925690, 546.883660);
    ctx.lineTo(304.822690, 546.883660);
    ctx.fill();
    
// #path3370
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(144, 218, 108)';
    ctx.moveTo(304.822690, 566.883660);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(305.002690, 566.883660, 305.168690, 566.985660, 305.258690, 567.149660);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(305.348690, 567.314660, 305.348690, 567.518660, 305.258690, 567.682660);
    ctx.lineTo(299.810690, 577.673660);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(299.720690, 577.838660, 299.554690, 577.940660, 299.373690, 577.940660);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(299.193690, 577.940660, 299.027690, 577.838660, 298.937690, 577.673660);
    ctx.lineTo(293.489690, 567.682660);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(293.398690, 567.518660, 293.398690, 567.314660, 293.489690, 567.149660);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(293.579690, 566.985660, 293.745690, 566.883660, 293.925690, 566.883660);
    ctx.lineTo(304.822690, 566.883660);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.restore();
    
// #g4301
    ctx.save();
    ctx.transform(1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, -8.000000, 0.000000);
    
// #path3374
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(68, 143, 228)';
    ctx.moveTo(355.300690, 577.940660);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(355.120690, 577.940660, 354.954690, 577.838660, 354.864690, 577.674660);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(354.774690, 577.508660, 354.774690, 577.305660, 354.864690, 577.141660);
    ctx.lineTo(360.312690, 567.149660);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(360.402690, 566.985660, 360.568690, 566.883660, 360.749690, 566.883660);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(360.929690, 566.883660, 361.095690, 566.985660, 361.185690, 567.149660);
    ctx.lineTo(366.633690, 577.141660);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(366.724690, 577.305660, 366.724690, 577.508660, 366.633690, 577.674660);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(366.543690, 577.838660, 366.377690, 577.940660, 366.197690, 577.940660);
    ctx.lineTo(355.300690, 577.940660);
    ctx.fill();
    
// #path3376
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(68, 143, 228)';
    ctx.moveTo(355.300690, 557.940660);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(355.120690, 557.940660, 354.954690, 557.838660, 354.864690, 557.674660);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(354.774690, 557.508660, 354.774690, 557.305660, 354.864690, 557.141660);
    ctx.lineTo(360.312690, 547.149660);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(360.402690, 546.985660, 360.568690, 546.883660, 360.749690, 546.883660);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(360.929690, 546.883660, 361.095690, 546.985660, 361.185690, 547.149660);
    ctx.lineTo(366.633690, 557.141660);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(366.724690, 557.305660, 366.724690, 557.508660, 366.633690, 557.674660);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(366.543690, 557.838660, 366.377690, 557.940660, 366.197690, 557.940660);
    ctx.lineTo(355.300690, 557.940660);
    ctx.fill();
    
// #path3378
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(68, 143, 228)';
    ctx.moveTo(355.300690, 537.940660);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(355.120690, 537.940660, 354.954690, 537.838660, 354.864690, 537.674660);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(354.774690, 537.509660, 354.774690, 537.305660, 354.864690, 537.141660);
    ctx.lineTo(360.312690, 527.150660);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(360.402690, 526.985660, 360.568690, 526.883660, 360.749690, 526.883660);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(360.929690, 526.883660, 361.095690, 526.985660, 361.185690, 527.150660);
    ctx.lineTo(366.633690, 537.141660);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(366.724690, 537.305660, 366.724690, 537.509660, 366.633690, 537.674660);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(366.543690, 537.838660, 366.377690, 537.940660, 366.197690, 537.940660);
    ctx.lineTo(355.300690, 537.940660);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.restore();
    
// #path4239
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.globalAlpha = 0.0;
    ctx.lineJoin = 'miter';
    ctx.arc(55.916168, 462.781710, 54.000000, 0.000000, 6.28318531, 1);
    
// #path4241
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.globalAlpha = 1.0;
    ctx.lineJoin = 'miter';
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgb(68, 143, 228)';
    ctx.miterLimit = 4;
    ctx.lineWidth = 4.539356;
    ctx.moveTo(55.965935, 421.849356);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(85.640371, 421.849356, 109.696255, 445.905241, 109.696255, 475.579680);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(109.696255, 505.254119, 85.640371, 529.310004, 55.965935, 529.310004);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(26.291499, 529.310004, 2.235615, 505.254119, 2.235615, 475.579680);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(2.235615, 445.905241, 26.291499, 421.849356, 55.965935, 421.849356);
    ctx.stroke();
    
// #path4241-2
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.globalAlpha = 1.0;
    ctx.lineJoin = 'miter';
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgb(68, 143, 228)';
    ctx.miterLimit = 4;
    ctx.lineWidth = 4.539356;
    ctx.moveTo(223.407520, 563.849326);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(253.081956, 563.849326, 277.137840, 587.905211, 277.137840, 617.579650);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(277.137840, 647.254089, 253.081956, 671.309974, 223.407520, 671.309974);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(193.733084, 671.309974, 169.677200, 647.254089, 169.677200, 617.579650);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(169.677200, 587.905211, 193.733084, 563.849326, 223.407520, 563.849326);
    ctx.stroke();
    
// #path4241-6
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.globalAlpha = 1.0;
    ctx.lineJoin = 'miter';
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgb(68, 143, 228)';
    ctx.miterLimit = 4;
    ctx.lineWidth = 4.539356;
    ctx.moveTo(584.297670, 421.849356);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(613.972106, 421.849356, 638.027990, 445.905241, 638.027990, 475.579680);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(638.027990, 505.254119, 613.972106, 529.310004, 584.297670, 529.310004);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(554.623234, 529.310004, 530.567350, 505.254119, 530.567350, 475.579680);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(530.567350, 445.905241, 554.623234, 421.849356, 584.297670, 421.849356);
    ctx.stroke();
    
// #path4241-2-3
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.globalAlpha = 1.0;
    ctx.lineJoin = 'miter';
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgb(68, 143, 228)';
    ctx.miterLimit = 4;
    ctx.lineWidth = 4.539356;
    ctx.moveTo(416.517330, 563.849326);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(446.191766, 563.849326, 470.247650, 587.905211, 470.247650, 617.579650);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(470.247650, 647.254089, 446.191766, 671.309974, 416.517330, 671.309974);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(386.842894, 671.309974, 362.787010, 647.254089, 362.787010, 617.579650);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(362.787010, 587.905211, 386.842894, 563.849326, 416.517330, 563.849326);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.restore();
    
// #layer3
    
// #g4306
    ctx.save();
    ctx.transform(1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, -11.362664, -296.837800);
    
// #path3396
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(144, 218, 108)';
    ctx.moveTo(390.705690, 453.977660);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(390.705690, 468.435660, 378.982690, 480.153660, 364.529690, 480.153660);
    ctx.lineTo(298.882690, 480.153660);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(284.424690, 480.153660, 272.705690, 468.435660, 272.705690, 453.977660);
    ctx.lineTo(272.705690, 388.331660);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(272.705690, 373.873660, 284.424690, 362.155660, 298.882690, 362.155660);
    ctx.lineTo(364.529690, 362.155660);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(378.982690, 362.155660, 390.705690, 373.873660, 390.705690, 388.331660);
    ctx.lineTo(390.705690, 453.977660);
    ctx.fill();
    
// #circle3398
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgb(242, 242, 242)';
    ctx.lineWidth = 4.000000;
    ctx.miterLimit = 10;
    ctx.arc(330.797700, 404.458650, 27.000000, 0.000000, 6.28318531, 1);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.restore();
    
// #line3400
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgb(242, 242, 242)';
    ctx.lineCap = 'round';
    ctx.miterLimit = 10;
    ctx.lineWidth = 4.000000;
    ctx.moveTo(319.435030, 94.120850);
    ctx.lineTo(319.435030, 121.120850);
    ctx.stroke();

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

It is not perfect, one line is missing at the bottom, you may have to fix that in code or draw SVG better (maybe my house shape path is not closed properly).

Comment: Would you happen to know why the layer transforms have weird translations? For example, in your example Layer 1 has a transform of: ctx.transform(1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, -0.297688, -299.579680); Where do the -.29 and -299 come from? Thanks.

Comment: @DoomGoober Sorry, but I have no idea at this moment. I have created this image few years before posting this answer. Maybe this is because group of object has been moved together and some properties of objects in this group didn't changed "inside group".

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out finally. The transform is the entire Inkscape layer that the shapes are on being translated. If I set the layer transform to identity, the .transform() completely goes away.

Answer (score 6):

I recommend the Java project [SVGToCanvas](http://code.google.com/p/lindenb/wiki/SVGToCanvas) if you just want to statically generate some Canvas javascript from a SVG file.

Comment: Perfect. Just what I was looking for. I knew it must be out there since the letters in the 'path' data stand for the same commands available in canvas.

Answer (score 4):

try this:

http://www.professorcloud.com/svg-to-canvas/

Answer (score 0):

If you want manipulate objects after conversion I recommend http://www.kineticjs.com/ it supports also SVG path data format. 
For instance: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-kineticjs-path-tutorial/.

It's pretty easy to loop through svg and change rectangles, paths, lines etc.. to coresponding kineticJS (canvas) objects.

Answer (score -2):

Here's my attempt!

http://appsynergy.net/projects/converting-svg-path-to-html5-canvas/

Answer (score -2):

Had same requirement for a couple internal projects. Thought it might help others, so it's available as an [SVG2Canvas](http://www.omnisoftsystems.com/?returnUrl=/iTrax/Home/svg2Canvas/0) experiment.

Comment: Unfortunately, that link is broken

Answer (score -18):

No. SVG is a (mostly) static vector format and canvas is an API to a dynamic bitmap. Turning SVG into canvas makes as much sense as turning SVG into MathML: none.