# Chrome gives a warning when loading an SVG in an <img>

Tags: html, google-chrome, canvas, svg, warnings

In order to display an SVG image file onto a canvas I have the following line on the HTML:

```
<img id="soundOnImg" src="img/speaker_on.svg" style="display:none"></img>
```

and then to draw it on the canvas I do:

```
ctx2d.drawImage($("#soundOnImg")[0], 10, 10, 200, 200);
```

(using jQuery `$()` there)

This works perfectly except for one annoyance - Chrome gives me the following warning:

```
Resource interpreted as image but transferred with MIME type image/svg+xml.
```

What does this warning mean?

I tried using `<object>` instead of `<img>` but this fails since the object element doesn't seem to have a `[0]` for some reason.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Looks similar to me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768565/drawing-a-svg-file-on-a-html5-canvas

Comment: It is, but that question lacks a proper answer to this question so I'm trying again.

Comment: I would treat this as a minor annoyance as you have categorized it. It doesn't affect your performance. And, am I correct to assume that jQuery and HTML5 Canvas are irrelevant here, that you get this warning just for having the `img src="...svg"`?

Comment: jQuery is indeed irrelevant but the canvas is. If I didn't need to draw it on the canvas I could have used a different way to embed the SVG, for instance using `<object>` or `<iframe>`

Comment: @shoosh Right, but even if you don't create a canvas or call `drawImage` you still see the warning, correct? So the question really is "Why does Chrome complain about this mime type when referencing SVG as an `img`?"

Comment: @shoosh I'm afraid I have to vote to close this as a duplicate, based on [these suggestions for handling this situation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49491/etiquette-for-duplicate-yet-unanswered-questions/49493#49493).

Comment: Modified the title to better reflect what this question is about. Thank you.

Comment: Happens in Safari 5, too (I don’t have 6 at hand to test) (Stack Overflow doesn’t allow more than 5 tags)

Answer (score 22):

This is a bug in the WebKit code bundled with Chrome. [WebInspector.Resource._checkWarning()](http://codesearch.google.com/codesearch/p#OAMlx_jo-ck/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/WebCore/inspector/front-end/Resource.js&l=608&exact_package=chromium) calls [WebInspector.Resource._mimeTypeIsConsistentWithType()](http://codesearch.google.com/codesearch/p#OAMlx_jo-ck/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/WebCore/inspector/front-end/Resource.js&l=574&exact_package=chromium) to check the mime-type of the resource. This function checks the value against the [WebInspector.MIMETypes](http://codesearch.google.com/codesearch/p#OAMlx_jo-ck/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/WebCore/inspector/front-end/inspector.js&l=1580&exact_package=chromium) object, which does not contain an entry for SVG images.

This does not appear to be fixed in [WebKit trunk](http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/WebCore/inspector/front-end/inspector.js#L1586), so you should probably [report it as a bug](http://www.webkit.org/quality/reporting.html).