# header warning for SVG as CSS background

Tags: html, css, apache, svg, http-headers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Chrome gives a warning when loading an SVG in an <img>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5065887/chrome-gives-a-warning-when-loading-an-svg-in-an-img)

I have a weird problem. the live demo of this problem is located at [beta.netbarg.com](http://beta.netbarg.com)

The problem is that, I have written a SVG file as the background property of an element. here is the stylesheet:

```
#lightburst {
    ...
    background: url('../nb2img/non-sprites/backlight.svg');
    ...
}
```

And According to [this link](http://kaioa.com/node/45) and [this one](https://jwatt.org/svg/authoring/) I have configured Apache to send `Content-Type: image/svg+xml` header for my SVG file.

**The weird part:**

- On Windows, everything is OK.
- On Linux (Ubuntu 10.4 - Chromium-browser/11) console logs a weird warning: `Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type image/svg+xml`

What's this? Is this a bug? how am I supposed to handle this warning?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5065887/html5-loading-an-svg-in-an-img-chrome-warning Chromium 18, Ubuntu, doesn't give the warning.

Comment: @DavidOliver That is a fixed bug in Webkit, I'm looking for the fix in Webkit's trunk to post here but my question is not the same bug because everything works fine under Windows.

Comment: Is it the same version on Chromium in Windows? The warning is the same...

Comment: @DavidOliver The Chromium version, no but the Webkit version, yes. I compiled it myself with the same version of my windows' chromium.

Comment: Have you tested in an actual standard recent version of Chromium in Linux?

Comment: @DavidOliver I've tested it with the standard/latest Chromium-browser which is located at Backtrack's repo and the same warning happened.