# Draw SVG on HTML5 Canvas with support for font element

Tags: html, canvas, svg

Is there a good library for converting SVG to HTML canvas that supports the font element? I have already tried [canvg](http://code.google.com/p/canvg/), but it does not support Font.

Comment: Fonts (and images) need to be embedded in the SVG for this to work: https://jsfiddle.net/ykx7kp8L/121/

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Browsers that support HTML5 Canvas also support SVG pretty well themselves. As such, you could do this:

```js
var img = new Image;
img.onload = function(){ myCanvasContext.drawImage(img,0,0); };
img.src = "foo.svg";
```

The only downside to this technique is that if the SVG is outside of your domain the canvas will become tainted; you will not be able to use `getImageData()` to read the resulting SVG, if that is your goal.

I've put an example of this technique on my server: http://phrogz.net/tmp/canvas_from_svg.html
I've tested this and verified that it works (and looks the same) on IE9, Chrome v11b, Safari v5, and Firefox v4.

**[Edit]** Note that:

1. <strike>Chrome and Firefox currently 'punt' on security and disallow you from reading the canvas (e.g. `getImageData()` or `toDataURL()`) after you draw *any* SVG to the canvas (regardless of the domain)</strike> **[these have been fixed](http://phrogz.net/SVG/svg_to_png.xhtml)**
2. Firefox currently has a bug where it refuses to draw SVG to the canvas unless the SVG has `height` and `width` attributes specified.

Comment: @Nilesh What OS and version of FireFox? It works for me using FF4.0 on Windows 7.

Comment: I have a svg as a string in javascript. I use it like `img.src = "data:image/svg+xml,"+svgString;` It works in chrome, but firefox refuses to parse `svgString` variable, as I have embedded style with CDATA.
Update: solved with encodeURIComponent(svgString)

Comment: this solution does not include a font! Can you add some text in a font like Arial ( anything but a serif Times ) and see if it still renders properly?

Comment: @headwinds It does. You can do that test and see it for yourself. (If you need help setting the font and drawing it, you want `.font = "…"` and `.fillText()`. [Here's a tutorial](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-text-font-size/).)

Comment: @Phrogz ok I see the difference - thanks - but if the original SVG has a special font face and you want to copy the SVG including the font face to the canvas by serializing the SVG, the font won't actually show up if you use .font on the canvas and here's why http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/5162/how-do-i-embed-google-web-fonts-into-an-svg - your solution is good but may not work in all cases depending on how the SVG is converted

Answer (score 13):

In case you have the svg embedded into HTML or as a raw source you can use a data URL to convert the svg to a HTML image element which you then can draw on the canvas:

```
var img = new Image();
// here attach an onload handler that draws the image on the canvas

// svgSource is the raw svg xml
img.src = "data:image/svg+xml," + encodeURIComponent(svgSource);
```

Comment: Note that with complex SVG content, you may run into size limitations for data: URIs -- in my case this meant I had no other options than to use canvg to draw a complex SVG.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried a simple img tag, Phrogs' method and canvg. My SVG has an embedded PNG. That only worked in canvg. The others showed the image without the embedded PNG. That was on Android Jellybean with either the standard browser or Chrome.