# drawing contents from iframe contenteditable onto an html5 canvas with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, canvas, contenteditable

Is there a way to draw or fill the contents of an iframe with contenteditable set to true on an html5 canvas?

Comment: Please clarify on your question, as your title and actual text seem to mean two different things. Do you want to take the contents that the user has typed in an iframe and capture a picture of them and draw it to a canvas? (As in steal a picture of their credit card details that you tricked them into entering.) Do you want to use a canvas as the background image for a contenteditable region?

Comment: @Phrogz The first part of your comment is what I am trying to do... Except for the "stealing information from the credit card".

Answer (score 2):

No. You cannot capture the browser's rendering of HTML elements as a picture with a canvas.

The only thing close to what you are describing is that you can take a serialized SVG file, get the browser to render it as an `img` element, and then [use `drawImage()` to write that image to the canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5495952/draw-svg-on-html5-canvas-with-support-for-font-element/5505861#5505861).