# How to detect the color of any position of an SVG area

Tags: javascript, svg

Within an SVG Area (not canvas) I need to determine the color of a specific coordinate (x,y) position using javascript. Overall something like this:

```
getColor (mySvgArea, x, y);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally in html links are drawn in a different colour if they have been visited than if they haven't. Such a thing is possible in SVG too of course and it was long ago realised that if you could figure out what the colour was it was a privacy leak and much effort was put into [fixing that](https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2010/03/31/plugging-the-css-history-leak/).

If you were allowed to read the colour at a general co-ordinate it would reopen the privacy leak so there will never be a way for you to do that outside of images.

The image way is to have your SVG in an `<image>` tag and then load it into a canvas. Browsers can prevent the privacy leak either by a) tainting the canvas so you can't read from it once SVG data has been loaded into it (Webkit currently) or b) resticting SVG image capability so they don't leak privacy by disabling things like link colouring (Firefox)

There is already a stackoverflow answer for with an example that [shows copying an SVG into canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5495952/draw-svg-on-html5-canvas-with-support-for-font-element). If you used Firefox you could then read the colour off.

Comment: very interesting. thanks for pointing the reason. To make SVG more powerful they should remove links ( which are rarely used ) from its specification. SVG needs more fine-grained control of the rendered graphics. In truth my research in this area is to be able to determine the boundaries of any given shape. A sort of intersection scan (since the getIntersectionList is not well supported yet).

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old topic, but there's another way to do it depending on your case. With SVG you can get an element using `Document.elementFromPoint` as well as you can get all underlying elements by hiding the top element and invoking `elementFromPoint` again. Color as well as other properties can be get from there. It doesn't really give you a color per se, but it's faster than canvas and works just fine for selected cases.