# Convert inline SVG to Base64 string

Tags: javascript, svg

I want to send an inline SVG image to a PHP script to Convert it to PNG with Imagick. For that I have to know how to get a base64 String out on an inline SVG. For canvas objects its a simple ".toDataURL()" but that doesn't work with inline SVGs, because its not a global function of elements.

```
test = function(){
    var b64 = document.getElementById("svg").toDataURL();
    alert(b64);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nikolang/ccx195qj/1/

But how to do it for inline SVGs?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5495952/4200092

Comment: Did anyone find the solution?

Answer (score 122, accepted):

Use [XMLSerializer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/XMLSerializer) to convert the DOM to a string

```
var s = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(document.getElementById("svg"))
```

and then [btoa](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64.btoa) can convert that to base64

```
var encodedData = window.btoa(s);
```

Just prepend the data URL intro i.e. `data:image/svg+xml;base64,` and there you have it.

Comment: This doesn't work  on the sample svg due to non-Latin1 characters in the text (btoa barfs on that). Tested on chrome 40.

Comment: It does indeed, on chrome too (stupid me had selected the wrong charset).

Comment: The solution works perfectly without converting it to base64. So only Serialising and then outputting it as a SVG object in HTML will work.

Comment: @richardj That would work sometimes i.e. on some content. You'd have to url encode the string to be sure of it working on any content.

Comment: I needed to unescape and encode the svg like so: `img.setAttribute("src", "data:image/svg+xml;base64," + btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))))`

Comment: I get Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'serializeToString' on 'XMLSerializer': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'. What am I doing wrong?  https://codepen.io/cssguru/pen/XZmGPO

Comment: @AdamYoungers You don't have any elements with id="svg", it's generally best to ask such things separately though

Comment: Oh snap!  Overlooked that as an HTML selector.

Comment: this is correct only if you svg+xml base64 works for you. this will not help if you need base64 png or jpeg

Comment: window.btoa(s) didnt work in my application, replacing this                          
  base64 = btoa(str.replace(/[\u00A0-\u2666]/g, function(c) {
    return '&#' + c.charCodeAt(0) + ';';
}));

Comment: This worked for me, but instead of using XMLSerializer, I used ReactDOMServer.renderToString as my element was not in the DOM but defined as a constant in React. Works just fine with btoa and url() in CSS.

Comment: @Prem Sanil: Great. Also I expanded the interval.. base64 = btoa(str.replace(/[\u0080-\uffff]/g, c => \`&#${c.charCodeAt(0)};\`));

Answer (score 24):

I just try to collect and explain all great ideas on this issue. This works on both Chrome 76 and Firefox 68

```
var svgElement = document.getElementById('svgId');

// Create your own image
var img = document.createElement('img');

// Serialize the svg to string
var svgString = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(svgElement);

// Remove any characters outside the Latin1 range
var decoded = unescape(encodeURIComponent(svgString));

// Now we can use btoa to convert the svg to base64
var base64 = btoa(decoded);

var imgSource = `data:image/svg+xml;base64,${base64}`;

img.setAttribute('src', imgSource);
```

Comment: in MDN there is a mark to not use `unescape` any more https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/unescape

Comment: @perymimon That leaves me a bit confused.  MDN says to use `decodeURIComponent` instead of `unescape`.  Is there a point to `decodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent())`?

Comment: @teepeemm probably not if after that you do 'btoa' any way

Comment: Thank you, unescape helped me find decodeURI, which works the same in my case.

Comment: This works amazingly, except it ignores all css styles.  Is there a way to inject styles before renders the image?

Answer (score 10):

You can do it relatively straightforwardly as follows.  The short version is

1. Make an image not attached to the dom
2. Set its size to match the source `svg`
3. `base64` encode the source `svg`, append the relevant data, set `img src`
4. Get the `canvas` context; `.drawImage` the image

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">


       window.onload = function() {
           paintSvgToCanvas(document.getElementById('source'), document.getElementById('tgt'));
       }



       function paintSvgToCanvas(uSvg, uCanvas) {

           var pbx = document.createElement('img');

           pbx.style.width  = uSvg.style.width;
           pbx.style.height = uSvg.style.height;

           pbx.src = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,' + window.btoa(uSvg.outerHTML);
           uCanvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(pbx, 0, 0);

       }


   </script>
   ```

   ```
   <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="467" height="462" id="source">
     <rect x="80" y="60" width="250" height="250" rx="20" style="fill:#ff0000; stroke:#000000;stroke-width:2px;" />
     <rect x="140" y="120" width="250" height="250" rx="40" style="fill:#0000ff; stroke:#000000; stroke-width:2px; fill-opacity:0.7;" />
   </svg>

   <canvas height="462px" width="467px" id="tgt"></canvas>
   ```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/oz3tjnk7/

Comment: Main **+** of this answer, is that it does **not use unnecessary `XMLSerializer`**, because simple **native `element.outerHTML` works** too :)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem while working on SVG based Floorplan Editor, after drawing a floorplan we have to save it for later use. Long story, code is better than talking, Here is the final code which worked for me:

```
async saveFloorplan() {
  const svgElem = document.querySelector('#svg-element');
  let xmlSource = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(svgElem);

  if (!xmlSource.match(/^<svg[^>]+xmlns="http:\/\/www\.w3\.org\/2000\/svg"/)) {
    xmlSource = xmlSource.replace(/^<svg/, '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"');
  }
  if (!xmlSource.match(/^<svg[^>]+"http:\/\/www\.w3\.org\/1999\/xlink"/)) {
    xmlSource = xmlSource.replace(/^<svg/, '<svg xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"');
  }
  // add xml declaration
  xmlSource = `<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>\r\n${xmlSource}`;

  const svg64 = encodeURIComponent(xmlSource);
  const b64Start = 'data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,';

  const imgEl = new Image();
  const image64 = b64Start + svg64;
  imgEl.src = image64;

  const blobResp = await fetch(imgEl.src);
  const blob = await blobResp.blob();

  const payload = {...}

  payload.fileExtension = 'svg';
  payload.fileSize = blob.size;

  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('file', blob);

  const uploaded = await api.uploadFile(formData);  
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This line will perform the conversion:

```
window.btoa($("svg").wrap("<div id='xyz'/>").parent().html());
```

Make sure that the proper charset/encoding has been selected!

Comment: If you don't base64 encode it you'll need to URL encode it as # is a reserved character which occurs rather frequently in colours.

Comment: @RobertLongson You are right that some sort of  encoding is necessary (b64 being convenient). I was referring to the specific extra code in the `Base64` object from the referenced SO answer. Any base 64 encoder that treats its input strictly as an octet sequence (as opposed to a character stream) will do.

Answer (score -1):

```
// 1. get the element
let e = document.getElementById("svg");

// 2. get the string representation of the element
var s = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(e);
// or 
var s = e.outerHTML;

// 3. convert the string to url
// convert to utf8
var url = "data:image/svg+xml;utf8," + encodeURIComponent(s);
// convert to base64
var url = "data:image/svg+xml;base64," + window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s)));
// or
var url = "data:image/svg+xml;base64," + Buffer.from(s, "utf-8").toString("base64")
```