# Encode svg image to base64 in javascript

Tags: javascript, svg, base64, xml-serialization

I have to encode svg images to base64 strings (for use in [jsPDF](https://parall.ax/products/jspdf)). I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28450471/convert-inline-svg-to-base64-string) which povides a way to do it using an svg element that's already in the DOM. But my svg images are in a folder on my server, and should not be displayed in the DOM.

Is there a way I can use this syntax

```
var s = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(something)
```

with an external image file (say, 'images/picture.svg') ?

Comment: Please read this post on codepen: very useful advices about how to [Optimize SVGs in data URIs](https://codepen.io/tigt/post/optimizing-svgs-in-data-uris). Also if you need to encode only one SVG image you may want to use this [URL-encoder for SVG](https://codepen.io/yoksel/pen/JDqvs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use JQuery to do that for example:

```
$.get("/my/nice/url/image.svg", function(data) {
  var s = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(data.documentElement)
  console.log(s)
  ...
});
```

Comment: ... and then encode as suggested in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28450471/convert-inline-svg-to-base64-string