# POST an SVG element/text to backend in (png/base64/other)

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, svg

[image]

I have an SVG with a "text" element

I need to POST to backend "text" as an image

Is there a way to convert "text" to png/base64/other?

Comment: Potential dupliacate of the question answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28450879/2444210 (That answer lets you convert the SVG into a data URI, which is base64 encoded, which you can send to the server.)

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand. What do you mean by "POST"?

Comment: @ChrisAkridge i need send the element as image to backend