# Angular - Img src attribute doesn't render SVG

Tags: html, angular, svg, angular11

I have an SVG file coming from the backend and when I try to display it in the frontend Angular(v11) app it doesn't render and looks broken.

Here is my code:

```
<div fxLayout="column" *ngFor="let svgFile of activePageDataChunk">
    <img src="data:image/svg+xml,svgFile">
```

This is how it looks like:

[image: file.svg]

This is content inside SVG:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="420mm" height="297mm">
  <rect width="100%" height="100%" id="paperBorder" fill="#FFF"/>
  <svg id="margins" x="5mm" y="5mm">
    <svg x="38.200050592422485mm" overflow="visible">
      <svg class="level_marker" x="0mm" y="28.509538173675537mm" overflow="visible">
        <text class="level_marker_text" font-size="12" y="-6" x="6mm" text-anchor="start">+0.000</text>
        <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="20mm" y2="0" fill="none" stroke="#231f20" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
        <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="2.5mm" y2="2.5mm" fill="none" stroke="#231f20" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
        <line x1="2.5mm" y1="2.5mm" x2="5mm" y2="0mm" fill="none" stroke="#231f20" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
      </svg>
      <svg class="level_marker" x="0mm" y="-2.490461826324463mm" overflow="visible">
        <text class="level_marker_text" font-size="12" y="-6" x="6mm" text-anchor="start">+3.100</text>
        <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="20mm" y2="0" fill="none" stroke="#231f20" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
        <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="2.5mm" y2="2.5mm" fill="none" stroke="#231f20" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
        <line x1="2.5mm" y1="2.5mm" x2="5mm" y2="0mm" fill="none" stroke="#231f20" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
      </svg>
    </svg>
  </svg>
  <svg x="0mm" y="195mm" width="83mm" height="22mm">
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="none" stroke="#666"/>
    <text x="1mm" y="2.5mm" font-size="2mm" font-family="DINPro-Light, DIN Pro" font-weight="300" style="isolation:isolate"/>
    <text x="1mm" y="7.5mm" font-size="4.5mm" font-family="DINPro, DIN Pro" style="isolation:isolate"/>
  </svg>
  <svg x="0mm" y="247mm" width="27.5mm" height="10mm">
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="none" stroke="#666"/>
    <text x="1mm" y="2.5mm" font-size="2mm" font-family="DINPro-Light, DIN Pro" font-weight="300" style="isolation:isolate">DATE</text>
    <text x="1mm" y="7.5mm" font-size="4.5mm" font-family="DINPro, DIN Pro" style="isolation:isolate">2.6.2022</text>
  </svg>
  <svg x="0mm" y="257mm" width="83mm" height="10mm">
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="none" stroke="#666"/>
    <text x="1mm" y="2.5mm" font-size="2mm" font-family="DINPro-Light, DIN Pro" font-weight="300" style="isolation:isolate">SCALE</text>
    <text x="50%" y="50%" alignment-baseline="central" text-anchor="middle" font-size="4.5mm" font-family="DINPro, DIN Pro" style="isolation:isolate">1:100</text>
  </svg>
  <svg x="0mm" y="277mm" width="83mm" height="10mm">
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="none" stroke="#666"/>
    <text x="1mm" y="2.5mm" font-size="2mm" font-family="DINPro-Light, DIN Pro" font-weight="300" style="isolation:isolate">DRAWN BY</text>
    <text x="1mm" y="7.5mm" font-size="4.5mm" font-family="DINPro, DIN Pro" style="isolation:isolate"/>
  </svg>
</svg>
```

Comment: Try with interpolation. `<img src="data:image/svg+xml,{{svgFile}}">`

Comment: doesn't work gives an error on chrome console `net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME`

Comment: Can you provide sample data for `activePageDataChunk`?

Comment: I have added details in the question

Comment: Hmmm, I don't think that is possible as provided data is SVG element, you can't render it in an `<img>` src unless you convert the SVG to base64 string. Or you can just straight render the SVG.

Comment: in this case how can I convert it to base64?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As discussed in the comment, the provided data was an SVG element, so you can't bind the value to the src of `<img>` element.

There are 2 ways to do it:

1. Convert SVG element to base64 string, so you can work with `<img>` element.
2. Bind the SVG element to HTML with `DOMSanitizer`.

**Answer 1**

To convert an SVG file to a base64 string, credit to this question: [Convert inline SVG to Base64 string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28450471/convert-inline-svg-to-base64-string)

```js
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

constructor(private _sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

getSVGImageUrl(image) {
  let base64string = btoa(image);
  return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(
    `data:image/svg+xml;base64,${base64string}`
  );
}
```

```
<div *ngFor="let svgFile of activePageDataChunk">
  <img [src]="getSVGImageUrl(svgFile)" />
</div>
```

[Sample StackBlitz Demo (Answer 1)](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zzam9k?file=src/app/app.component.html)

---

**Answer 2**:

```js
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

constructor(private _sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

getSVGImage(image) {
  return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(`${image}`);
}
```

```
<div *ngFor="let svgFile of activePageDataChunk">
  <div [innerHTML]="getSVGImage(svgFile)"></div>
</div>
```

[Sample StackBlitz Demo (Answer 2)](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-uriyar?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

---

**Reference**

[WARNING: sanitizing unsafe style value url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38593515/warning-sanitizing-unsafe-style-value-url) (Similar question)

[DomSanitizer `bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl()`](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer#bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl)

[DomSanitizer `bypassSecurityTrustHtml()`](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer#bypasssecuritytrusthtml)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer I have tried above solution earlier but it expose app to xss

Comment: Hi, I added answer 1 for converting SVG to base64 string. You may have a read. Thanks.