# Manipulate mid-points of SVG path after animation

Tags: svg

I've got an [SVG path which animates drawing out a word](http://codepen.io/dcdev/pen/pwEdH).  After the animation is finished, the letters should begin to drip downward as though the text had been written in paint.  The only solution I've come up with is to do it as a gif.

Is it possible to manipulate the path of the SVG after its drawn to create the effect?

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_3" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="-510.061 200.082 424.13 251.322" style="enable-background:new -510.061 200.082 424.13 251.322;" xml:space="preserve" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
  <path class="path" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="url(#g)" stroke-width="14" stroke-miterlimit="4" d="M-452.825,292.283
    c-38.797-6.45-55.673,31.665-54.141,39.691c0.623,3.262,1.864,2.683,6.84,2.886c3.018,0.123,12.397-2.326,16.621-5.22
    c9.716-6.655,13.538-11.867,13.538-11.867c1.06-1.231,2.76-1.456,4.78-1.316c1.963,0.136,15.194,26.35,15.847,27.428
    c12.207,20.147,9.337,62.703,8.847,65.677c-3.361,20.419-33.532,55.715-42.439,29.547c-26.299-77.26,38.171-82.38,44.621-80.93
    c13.822,3.106,12.376-10.28,11.743-13.3c-1.432-6.83-2.462-9.788-4.061-13.002c-4.008-8.06-8.904-16.999-8.176-17.467
    c0.609-0.391-1.198,9.376,3.546,8.939c5.93-0.547,2.76-11.961,10.312-17.145c8.707-5.976,12.009-7.347,11.635-6.931
    c-4.204,4.679-18.594,13.802-19.442,18.848c-1.09,6.479-1.73,27.306,13.344,32.355c6.558,2.197,35.442-58.24,37.348-68.115
    c1.724-8.93-0.305-10.748-0.858-11.172c-2.443-1.871-6.648,0.054-7.167,0.292c-7.02,3.215-10.192,8.651-10.74,10.289
    c-2.197,6.558-3.699,15.481,1.89,18.896c5.971,3.649,9.229,4.618,15.819-9.204c2.064-4.329,4.088-11.676,4.114-13.368
    c0.07-4.595,1.431-4.653,2.944-0.539c8.273,22.494,16.686,19.444,30.462,34.976c5.15,5.807,21.282,23.499,31.24,63.769
    c0.928,3.752-6.903,6.553-8.139,2.891c-8.315-24.633-10.271-34.758-15.895-50.381c-15.16-42.111-1.753-13.414-28.475-71.059
    c1.661-1.142,6.421-3.193,11.871-4.381c5.702-1.242,14.565-1.38,15.939,5.132c1.989,9.427-12.222,18.347-15.609,28.852
    c-6.35,19.69,0.48,32.902,5.927,29.905c34.808-19.149,27.865-13.051,31.663-20.621c1.556-3.102,0.943-9.097,0.931-12.031
    c-0.061-14.49-19.911-58.049-21.116-57.597c-1.317,0.494,21.932,65.597,25.712,64.607c2.049-0.537-9.917-16.161-6.63-26.456
    c0.884-2.767,1.444-7.339,8.422-7.099c19.793,0.683,20.382,29.092,24.906,34.772c2.265,2.843,9.185-24.448-3.663-60.94
    c16.114,37.598,13.059,48.655,12.918,47.193c-3.072-31.917,1.788-49.326,20.006-50.841c9.18-0.764,16.58-1.225,16.58-1.225
    s-35.881,3.339-36.249,17.898c-0.16,6.348,6.265,16.546,12.222,17.616c13.478,2.42,31.955-14.112,39.648-39.058
    c2.094-6.789,22.84-20.669,23.074-20.388c0.415,0.498-49.858,35.959,7.977,20.739c32.55-8.566,25.661,19.843-8.652,30.146
    c-29.735,8.929-31.283,17.326-71.967,30.749c-70.138,23.141-90.571,28.35-126.316,46.254c-40.064,20.067-60.502,35.66-60.502,35.66
    s228.985-125.861,373.43-146.017"/>
  <linearGradient id="g">
<stop offset="0.10" stop-color="#0ef1ff"/>
<stop offset="0.15" stop-color="#37c8ff"/>
<stop offset="0.20" stop-color="#58a7ff"/>
<stop offset="0.25" stop-color="#7a85ff"/>
<stop offset="0.30" stop-color="#ac53ff"/>
<stop offset="0.35" stop-color="#d22dff"/>
<stop offset="0.40" stop-color="#f20dff"/>
<stop offset="0.45" stop-color="#fe4cb8"/>
<stop offset="0.50" stop-color="#fe7394"/>
<stop offset="0.55" stop-color="#fd9376"/>
<stop offset="0.60" stop-color="#fdb05b"/>
<stop offset="0.65" stop-color="#fccf3e"/>
<stop offset="0.70" stop-color="#faec21"/>
<stop offset="0.75" stop-color="#d4c81c"/>
<stop offset="0.80" stop-color="#a49b15"/>
<stop offset="0.85" stop-color="#7d7610"/>
<stop offset="0.90" stop-color="#57520b"/>
<stop offset="0.95" stop-color="#353207"/>
<stop offset="1" stop-color="#000000"/>
</linearGradient> 
</svg>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can render the SVG to a Canvas (at runtime) and then do pixel manipulation.

[Drawing an SVG file on a HTML5 canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768565/drawing-a-svg-file-on-a-html5-canvas)

An alternative approach would be to include "dripping paint" graphic elements in your SVG that are hidden initially, but are then revealed by changing their opacity, or animating the drip shapes.