# Read SVG Elements in Java and Skip Certain Elements which have Text

Tags: java, xml, canvas, svg, schema

I need to Read an SVG and Render that on Canvas. But the problem is, I need to skip certain elements which contains the text I don't want. I know that specific text ( its not dynamic).

I am thinking of getting All the xml schema into java code and then delete those nodes and then push to client and paste on canvas via jQuery.

What method would be the best? And how?

Comment: My point is, If its possible that I can read the DOM elements of SVG into an object, skip those who I dont require and parse that object to canvas in web page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use jQuery (or just plain JS) to select the elements you don't want. Then set `display` to `"none"`

```js
$("text:contains('here')").css("display", "none");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<svg>
  <text y="50">Hello</text>
  <text y="100">There</text>
</svg>
```

Comment: But how to put on canvas?

Comment: You can use the canvg library.  Or see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768565/drawing-a-svg-file-on-a-html5-canvas