# Draw SVG Using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, svg

I'm trying to recreate [this](http://tympanus.net/Development/AnimatedHeaderBackgrounds/index3.html) background animation but instead of the random triangles that are drawn using javascript, I want to use three different SVG files.

I tried to replicate the function through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768565/drawing-a-svg-file-on-a-html5-canvas) SO article, but couldn't quite get it right.

So my main question is, how and where would I need to manipulate the script to draw SVG's instead of the triangles it's doing now. Or if it's even possible?

My guess would be that it has to do with this part of the script but I'm not 100% sure:

```
this.draw = function() {
    if(_this.alpha >= 0.005) _this.alpha -= 0.005;
    else _this.alpha = 0;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(_this.coords[0].x+_this.pos.x, _this.coords[0].y+_this.pos.y);
    ctx.lineTo(_this.coords[1].x+_this.pos.x, _this.coords[1].y+_this.pos.y);
    ctx.lineTo(_this.coords[2].x+_this.pos.x, _this.coords[2].y+_this.pos.y);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba('+_this.color+','+ _this.alpha+')';
    ctx.fill();
};
```

Thanks in advance for any help and let me know if I need to clarify the issue a little more.

Comment: You could redraw the same svg with random colors each time and width/height (and ofcourse whatever other thing you want random)

Comment: you are talking about SVG but posted canvas code.. am i missing some thing here??

Comment: Per that article you link in the question you want to use ctx.drawImage

Comment: @RobertLongson my question is where would I add that bit of code to the script?

Comment: replace all the existing ctx. calls with ctx.drawImage calls. You really want a book on canvas at this point as its hard to learn from scratch in a Q&A way.