# How can i rotate custom puspin dynamically using bingmaps v7

Tags: bing-maps, bing-api, pushpin

Anyone please help me I am using `bing map api v7` module I added initially some `pushpins` (like cars/aeroplanes these all are `svg` code) when I am updating my `pushpin`(car) some times I want to rotate my `pushpin`. If any one knows please give a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the Bing Maps V8 control instead of V7 (V7 is nearing end of life). The documentation for V8 actually has an example of rotating a pin here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt712689.aspx

It uses the HTML5 canvas. Note that you can easily draw SVG's on to HTML5 canvases. Here is a post with an example: [Drawing an SVG file on a HTML5 canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768565/drawing-a-svg-file-on-a-html5-canvas)