# Blurry svg in canvas

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas, svg

Why SVG doesn't scale correctly in canvas (it is all pixelated and blurry) ?
What am I doing wrong ?

All I want is the SVG image to keep it's aspect ratio whatever the canvas size, and alose not have it becoming blurry.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("screen"),
  ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var img = new Image();
img.src = "http://imgh.us/perso.svg";
img.onload = function() {
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#screen {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
  <title>Game</title>
</head>

<body>
  <canvas id="screen"></canvas>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/game.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Why are you putting it into a canvas?  Once it's in a canvas element, it is rasterized.  It's no longer a Scalable **Vector** Graphic, it's pixels.  Just place the SVG element into the DOM itself.

Comment: I wanted to make a game using canvas and SVG images. I thought it would still be an SVG... Guess I have to read even more about what canvas really are. Thanks for you clarification !

Comment: I'm not trying to deter you.  If you have a real reason for wanting to use SVG in canvas, then you should add that as a detail in your question.  Maybe take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3769883/691711)

Comment: I wanted to use SVG in canvas so it could easily scale up for any resolution. I guess it's not as easy as I thought it would be. And don't worry, I am not giving up. Will also elaborate more my future questions.

Comment: @newbStudent any update on this? were you able to render a clear image from svg using the solution given below? If yes, what did you do exactly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem isn't with the SVG, it's with the canvas.

Canvases have a default size of 300 × 150. The first thing, wich runs is the script, it creates the canvas context, wich is 300 × 150. Then CSS comes, and scales the canvas element to 100% in each direction. The context is still 300 × 150. This makes every pixel take up more than 1 pixel area. You need to make sure your script runs after the CSS or you need to use javascript, to resize the canvas.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I will take a look on how to run js after CSS, or simply go for another solution.

Comment: @newbStudent If you have the js in a separate file (wich you should have), then simply add a `defer="defer"` property to the script element

Comment: @newbStudent, the solution is just to set your canvas `width` and `height` properties. It won't change anything to run the script after the css has loaded if you don't set it.

Answer (score -2):

I think you can put the SVG inside a `div` and then blur the div,so it will get the same effect

https://jsfiddle.net/moongod101/q3qh78xd/

Comment: In fact, I wanted to avoid the blurry effect. But thanks for your answer !