# Exporting HTML5's <svg> tag

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, svg

I am using HTML 5 svg tag to render some graphical objects. What I need is a way to export the drawn graphics into a file. I know that the good old "canvas" tag can do that as simple as:

```
var img = myCanvas.toDataURL("image/png");
```

So my question is simple - Can I do something similar with the svg tag or is there any way to convert the svg to canvas so that i can export the canvas?

Thanks!

PS: I have many reasons and constraints to use svg tag over canvas, so changing my implementation is not an option here.

Comment: http://fabricjs.com/ might do the trick for you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert SVG to image (JPEG, PNG, etc.) in the browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975499/convert-svg-to-image-jpeg-png-etc-in-the-browser)

Comment: just draw the svg into the canvas and then get the image from the canvas. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768565/drawing-a-svg-file-on-a-html5-canvas

Comment: I am generating the image in HTML manner, I do not have an image that I display in a canvas. Therefor I use third party libraries so that I can generated (based on some computing logics what to be drawn). These libraries are using svg over canvas (I do believe it is for a reason).

Comment: Svg is a perfectly fine image format. Why not just use that?

Comment: @HolgerWill I am using http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_svg.asp not a file.