# Canvas Context Sometimes Returns Only Zeros

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to compare two svg images for equality. To do this I first convert them to Canvas (using this post [Drawing an SVG file on a HTML5 canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768565/drawing-an-svg-file-on-a-html5-canvas) as a guide). Then I extract the pixel data arrays from each Canvas and determine if each element of both arrays are equal.

This works in the general case, but the first time data is extracted from a Canvas in a particular instance of a web page, it returns an array containing only zeros.

For instance, the code below contains some inline js. When an html file containing only this code is first opened in a browser (I've tried firefox and chromium) an array containing only zeros is printed to the console. However if the page is refreshed, the desired array (one with 255 in all the blue and alpha positions) is printed to the console.

Can anyone tell me why this happens and if there's any way to get around it so that the desired array is always returned?

```
<script>
  // create canvas
  let can = document.createElement('canvas');
  // get canvas context
  let ctx = can.getContext('2d');

  // svg markup
  let xml = '<svg viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20" data-reactroot=""><rect x="0" y="0" width="20" height="20" fill="rgba(0, 0, 255, 1)"></rect></svg>';

  // make it base64
  let svg64 = btoa(xml);
  // header
  let b64Start = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,';
  // prepend header
  let image64 = b64Start + svg64;

  // set it as the source of a img element
  let img = document.createElement('img');
  img.src = image64;

  // draw the image onto the canvas
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

  // extract pixel data from context
  let data = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 20, 20).data;

  // print pixel data somewhere we can see it
  console.log(data);
</script>
```

Comment: You probably have to wait for the image to load before drawing it, even though it’s a data URI. It has an `onload` event.

Comment: @Ry- is perfectly correct. Adding a listener fixes everything.